# List and Execute Oozie jobs from the command line

Tags: oozie

I just deployed a oozie job. Now when I go to the oozie web ui ... i just cannot see the job I deployed.

Is there a command line tool which will allow me to do two things

1. List all the jobs which are deployed (not running, active, killed)... but deployed. like an inventory of all jobs.
2. execute a job from the command line. (on demand, not based on schedule).

Comment: What do you mean by "job": a Workflow, or a Coordinator? What do you mean by "deploy": did you run it, did you submit it?

Comment: In the main page for Oozie documentation, there is an entry for "Command-line tool". And believe it or not, the CLI for Oozie is named `oozie`. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html

Comment: You also have a half-decent monitoring console for recent Workflows executions (and running Coordinators) in Hue.

Answer (score 11):

As already mentioned in one of the comments that `oozie`in itself is a command line tool.

Therefore, to answer both of your questions:

1. List all jobs

   - For listing all `workflow` jobs use the following command

     1. `oozie jobs`
     2. `oozie jobs -jobtype wf`
   - For listing all `coordinator` jobs use the following command from the console

     1. `oozie jobs -jobtype coordinator`
2. Execute a job from command line

   - `oozie job --oozie http://oozie-url:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run`

Mind you that if you want to keep on starting on demand job either you have to run the above command manually (also only for workflow jobs, not for coordinator jobs as coordinator jobs would be scheduled according to the schedule you define) or put in a shell script so that it is triggered under certain situations

For more info check this link - [Oozie_Command_Line_Usage](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Oozie_Command_Line_Usage)

Comment: i am following your answer but getting "Exception = Connection timed out"
 error.

Comment: Are you on the correct oozie-url and port? and do you have access to it from the machine you are using?

Comment: actually i am using localhost only, but i am working in SSH secure shell , and other IP address.  oozie job --oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run

Comment: You need to be sure oozie is running on the server and the correct port you are referring to(even if its your local machine, try giving the full qualified name)

Comment: thank you. now it is connected but now problem is like status is showing only RUNNING, it is not changing only. what might be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure, you may create a new question with a bit more details, and then I or someone else can take a look.